# Adding missing brackets for text to speech silence codes in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am current trying to make a macro to find broken silence codes and add that missing bracket.
It worked the first time around but it stopped working

Basically this should fix something like:

John [slnc 50]] Doe [[slnc 50]

to

John [[slnc 50]] Doe [[slnc 50]]

The tempArray will have more items in it, both longer and shorter pauses, but i put like three as an example

```
Dim var As String
Dim tempArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

                           ' Example
tempArray = Array("[[slnc 0]]", "[[slnc 25]]", "[[slnc 50]]")

For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
    var = tempArray(i)
   
 ' Check if the opening bracket is missing
    If Left(var, 2) <> "[[" Then
        var = "[[" & var
    End If
    
    ' Check if the closing bracket is missing
    If Right(var, 2) <> "]]" Then
        var = var & "]]"
    End If

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = var
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next
```

TL;DR: Needed this to add missing brackets, worked once and never again. Wondering what i am missing or what i could add

Comment: I can’t see how the code you have posted could ever have worked as all of the parameters that tell `Find` what to look for and what to replace it with are missing.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt ok, i added a part of the code i had commented out originally since it deletes all bracketed items, im new to this so apologies

Comment: If Left(var, 2) <> "[[" Then
        var = "[[" & var
    End If
So if var = [foo]] bar var will be [[[foo]]bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `tempArray will have more items in it, both longer and shorter pause` You don't have to keep maintaining the list.
- ***Assuming*** there are no more than two consecutive square brackets (eg. `[[[`) in the document, otherwise, additional code would be needed to handle it.
- The code replaces all instances in Word doc.
- Note: `||` is used as a temp delimiter char. If you use it in the doc, using other char works well (eg. `##`).

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceBracket()
    Dim aTxt, sRepTxt As String, i As Long
    aTxt = Array("\[\[([!\[\]]@)\]\]", "\[([!\[\]]@)\]\]", "\[\[([!\[\]]@)\]", "||([!\[\]]@)||")
    For i = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
        sRepTxt = IIf(i = UBound(aTxt), "[[\1]]", "||\1||")
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchByte = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = aTxt(i)
            .Replacement.Text = sRepTxt
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]